# Search an ArrayList using an object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` that is defined as follows:

```
ArrayList<Doctor> arr = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
```

The `Doctor` class contains the following:

```
String name;
String gender;
String speciality;
```

In the `arr` arraylist i have added 100 Doctor objects.

Now i need to search the `arr` ArrayList to see if a particular doctor object is present.

I tried the following approach;

boolean contains = maarrp.containsKey(doc.name);

But, i don't want to compare using `keys` or an `element` of the `Doctor` object. Instead i want to compare the whole `doctor` object. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in `Doctor` class.

your class should be something like :

```
class Doctor
{
  String name;
  String gender;
  String speciality;

public boolean equals()
{
  //some logic on which you want to say 
  //two doctors are same.
  return true;
}

 public int hashCode()
 {
   return 0;
 }
}
```

for hashCode you must follow these rules :

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
>   If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
>   It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

Note : hashCode must not always return 0 :)

Comment: +1, but you should expand this answer a bit, otherwise it's more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to  implement the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in you Doctor Object then  Search against ArrayList like below.

```
ArrayList<Doctor> arr = new ArrayList<Doctor>();

arr.add(new Doctor());
arr.add(new Doctor());
arr.add(new Doctor());
arr.add(new Doctor());

if(arr.contains(doc){

}
```

Create your Doctor class like below

```
class Doctor{

        Long id;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Doctor other = (Doctor) obj;
            if (id == null) {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in Doctor Class

```
/*add a unique id field in doctor class to make each doctor unique.*/
String docUniqueId; 
String name;
String gender;
String speciality;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object ob) {
    if (!ob instanceof Doctor ) return false;
    Doctor that = (Doctor )ob;
    return this.docUniqueId== that.docUniqueId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return docUniqueId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the equals() and hashcode() methods of your Doctor class. These methods are called when the contains() method of the ArrayList object is called.

To simplify this work, you can eventually use the commons-lang library which provides:

EqualsBuilder (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html)

and HashCodeBuilder (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html)